# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01/20/2018 12:15 PM" (at offset 17)

Tags: android, date

The actual problem is the phone supported time format has a.m. & p.m. not AM/PM
1)it's working fine when which phone has AM/PM format
2)Not working for which phone has a.m. & p.m.

```
 String strDate = "01/20/2018 12:15 PM";
    SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    try {
        Date date = dateF.parse(strDate);
        String convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(date);
        tickets.TimeDue = convertDate;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be related with the Locale/Timezone definition you are using.

You can add `Locale.ENGLISH` to your code .

Change

```
SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Thanks will check.

Comment: Could you slove your problem ?@ArulKumar

Answer (score 0):

replace `unparseable p.m.` to `PM` like below code

```
 String strDate = "01/20/2018 12:15 p.m.";
    SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        Date date = null;
        if (strDate.contains("p.m.")){
            strDate = strDate.replace("p.m.","PM");
            date = dateF.parse(strDate);
            String convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(date);
             tickets.TimeDue = convertDate;
        }else if(strDate.contains("a.m.")){
            strDate = strDate.replace("a.m.","AM");
            date = dateF.parse(strDate);
            String convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(date);

             tickets.TimeDue = convertDate;
        }else {
            date = dateF.parse(strDate);
            String convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(date);
            tickets.TimeDue = convertDate;
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```